# How to set the name of a Docker container using REST API

Tags: docker

I am attempting to create and start a container via the REST API.  That is, using the following API:

```
curl --http1.0 --request POST --header "Content-Type: application.json" http://$DOCKER_HOST:4243/containers/create --data @create.json
```

where create.json is a JSON file of desired properties. I would like to assign a specific name to the container. One can do this via the docker CLI using the --name parameter on the run command:

```
docker run --name "my_name" my_image
```

The documentation for creating a container (https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.15/#create-a-container) provides an example JSON payload. A name attribute is not listed.  I tried the following variations for a name attribute:

```
"Name": "my_name"
"Names": [ "my_name" ]
"Names": [ "/my_name" ]
"Name": "/my_name"
```

all to no avail. The variations are inspired by the results of a query:

```
curl --http1.0 http://$DOCKER_HOST:4243/containers/json
```

which returns entries that include:

```
"Names":["/elegant_mccarthy"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You include `name` as a query param, not in the JSON.

From the docs (on the page you linked):

> Query Parameters:
>
> name – Assign the specified name to the container. Must match /?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+.

So probably something like:

```
curl --http1.0 --request POST --header "Content-Type: application.json" http://$DOCKER_HOST:4243/containers/create?name=your-name --data @create.json
```

**When in doubt:**

You can use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to sit between your Docker CLI calls and the unix socket it uses to talk to the daemon to see exactly what's happening when you use the `docker` client, since it just talks to the API itself.

In one terminal:

```
socat -t100 -v UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/proxysocket.sock,mode=644,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And in another terminal:

```
export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///tmp/proxysocket.sock"
docker run -ti --name=test ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

And you'll be able to see in the output of the first terminal:

> 2014/10/26 02:20:15.176744  length=564 from=0 to=563
>
> **POST /v1.15/containers/create?name=test HTTP/1.1\r**
>
> Host: /tmp/proxysocket.sock\r
>
> User-Agent: Docker-Client/1.2.0-dev\r
>
> Content-Length: 370\r
>
> Content-Type: application/json\r
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip\r

Comment: I was not sufficiently clear -- I want to create the container, not query for it.  I've edited the question in an attempt to make this more clear.

Comment: You were sufficiently clear - I just copied your curl request. I've updated by answer with your new curl request.

Comment: Thank you!!  I should have realized that it would be a good idea to go back and reread the documentation instead of assuming that I recalled it.  Worked perfectly.